# Isotope in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I want to create Isotope design in `javascript` or `angular JS`. But not in `jquery`. So can anyone tell me how I do this?

This design is purely based on an array. i.e using this array isotope design is created in html page.
I know isotope metafizzy(http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) but this is external Library. I required isotope design without any use of external library. So can anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It would help a lot if you could show us what you already have tried. So please post the code you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this [project](https://github.com/mankindsoftware/angular-isotope)

which implements just what you're looking for.